# No route matches :action => edit rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I don’t understand why I am getting the above error message when trying to update a recipe

This is my output of rake routes

```
      recipes GET    /recipes(.:format)                recipes#index
              POST   /recipes(.:format)                recipes#create
   new_recipe GET    /recipes/new(.:format)            recipes#new
  edit_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format)       recipes#edit
       recipe GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)            recipes#show
              PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)            recipes#update
              DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)            recipes#destroy
         root        /                                 public_pages#index
```

My controller looks like this

```
def edit
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

  if @recipe.update_attributes(params[:recipe])
    redirect_to recipes_path, :notice => "Successfully updated recipe"
  else 
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

And my link to edit the post

```
<%= link_to "Edit Recipe", edit_recipe_path(@recipe) %>
```

the full error is (this is when trying to access the recipes page

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"recipes"}

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

and finally the form i am using, now the only thing I can think of is that there is an issue with my form, though i thought that you could use the same form for new and edit? though i could be totally wrong

Anyone have any ideas

Comment: Add the first few lines of your error backtrace, then we (and you) can see if the error is from the controller or from the view.

Comment: @Thilo, is that what you meant (check edit towards end of question)

Comment: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"recipes"}` => there's no ID, therefore maybe `@recipe` is not instantiated when you do `edit_recipe_path(@recipe)`?

Comment: Don't forget to rescue from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` errors when your `find` call can't get a record.

Comment: @Richlewis No, but I forgot there is not backtrace for routing errors. My bad :)

Answer (score 2):

ok so it seems as if i needed this in my view

```
 <%= link_to "Edit Recipe", edit_recipe_path(r.id) %>
```

this was because i was passing

```
 <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
```